# Upload Image on Server Without converting into BITMAP

Tags: android

I am **Selecting Image from Gallery, ** sending Text and Image but I am able to see only Text, Not Image.
**Actually I don't want to use Bitmap or compress file which I am sending over to Server.** Please guide em how can I send My Image without compressing and Converting into BitMap.. **I am using here BitMap but I want To REMOVE THIS CODE**

```
 private void uploadData() {

    if (etNormalText.getText().toString().trim().isEmpty()) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please Type Status", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else if (null != mProgressDialog) {
        imageUpload = getStringImage(bitmap);
        mProgressDialog.setMessage("Uploading...");
        mProgressDialog.show();

        mapobject = signatureobject(etNormalText.getText().toString().trim());
        new PostStringRequest(CreateStreamActivity.this, mapobject, CreateStreamActivity.this, UPLOAD_TEXT, NetworkUtility.create_stream);
    }

}

public String getStringImage(Bitmap bitmap) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    this.bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, baos);
    byte[] imageBytes = baos.toByteArray();
    imageUpload = Base64.encodeToString(imageBytes, Base64.DEFAULT);
    return imageUpload;
}


@Override
public void onSuccess(String result, String type) {
    if (type.equals(UPLOAD_TEXT)) {
        mProgressDialog.dismiss();
        Log.d("Create Stream Upload", "onSuccess: " + result);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Posted Successfully...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        finish();
    }
}

@Override
public void onFailure(int responseCode, String responseMessage) {

}

private Map<String, String> signatureobject(String editNormal) {

    mapobject = new HashMap<>();
    mapobject.put("access_key", NetworkUtility.accesskey);
    mapobject.put("timestamp", Utility.timestamp());
    mapobject.put("session_key", NetworkUtility.session_key);
    mapobject.put("signature", "");
    mapobject.put("text", editNormal);
    mapobject.put("media[]", imageUpload);

    return mapobject;

}
```

Comment: u can send base64 encode of image as string to server

Comment: Change this  mapobject.put("media[]", imageUpload);
to  mapobject.put("media", imageUpload);

Comment: "I am Selecting Image from Gallery" -- you have no code for this in your question. "Please guide em how can I send My Image without compressing and Converting into BitMap" -- the code in your question starts with the `Bitmap` already. If you want assistance in removing that code, we would have to see what that code is and what it does.

Comment: you can try directly uploading the image as a file (binary data) from storage insteadof handling bitmaps, and looks like you are using retrofit, so okhttp has an ease way of doing that once you have that `file` or `Uri` object.

Answer (score 2):

We Can Upload Images to server without Converting to Bitmap Check This Link

> https://guides.codepath.com/android/Networking-with-the-Fast-Android-Networking-Library

we just need to pass the image path which you will get from the gallary.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer this link you may get the answer. http://www.androidhive.info/2014/12/android-uploading-camera-image-video-to-server-with-progress-bar/